# Disable specific rows in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using react-table v7.6.3 where I am allowing users to edit some data in the table. I intend to use WebSockets to prevent another user from editing the same row of data that a user is already editing. For that, I need to disable rows in react-table. Can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code ?